# Is there a way to refactor all table-names and column-names of a PowerBI (PBIX) dashboard through Visual Studio Code or any other IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, powerbi, refactoring

I have about 25-30 odd tables in the PowerBI app. reading from a SQL database. The application is towards the end-stages of development, and now business wants things renamed using new conventions and this technically means a lot of rework to manually go 1 table at a time to refactor in PBI. Is there a way in PBI, like how we could simply refactor a C-Sharp/Java codebase through an IDE like Visual Studio/IntelliJ by easily renaming something at one place only and it auto-refactors where-ever that dependency exists?